# Entity Framwork Core Lambda Function not early terminating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using asp.net core with entityframework.

When making an API call to get a list of entities i pass an optional filter in json which could look like this:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "customer.id": 1
}
```

In my ControllerAction I am first deserializing the JSON and then I am querying against the DB.

```
var dynamicfilter = filter != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(filter) : new Dictionary<string, string>();

List<User> Users = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Customer).Where(u =>
    dynamicfilter.Keys.Count > 0 ? (
        (dynamicfilter.ContainsKey("name") ? u.Name.ToLower().Contains(dynamicfilter["name"].ToLower()) : true) &&
        (dynamicfilter.ContainsKey("customer.id") ? u.Customer.ID == Convert.ToInt32(dynamicfilter["customer.id"]) : true)
    ) : true).ToList();
```

This works as long as all filter parameters are set. If at least one filter parameter is not set, a null reference is thrown because even if the `ContainsKey()` is `false` the code between ? and : is executed.

But if I first load the whole table and apply the filter locally, by doing it like that

```
List<User> Users = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Customer).ToList().Where(...
```

it works like a charm.
Is there a way to make it work on Database-Side too?

Comment: Could you please add all relevant error messages.

Comment: The LINQ to SQL engin is probably not able to convert the `b ? a : b` operation of your where clause.

Comment: The Error Message is: 'KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'name' was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.get_Item(TKey key)

InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. To show additional information call EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring.'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the logic out of the query. Like:

```
IQueryable<User> query = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Customer);
query = dynamicfilter.ContainsKey("name") 
    ? query.Where(u=>u.Name.ToLower().Contains(dynamicfilter["name"].ToLower()) 
    : query;
query = dynamicfilter.ContainsKey("customer.id") 
    ? query.Where(u=>u.Customer.ID == Convert.ToInt32(dynamicfilter["customer.id"])) 
    : query;

List<User> Users = query.ToList(); // DB query executed here
```

This way the expression tree will be build in the `query` object and executed only on enumeration attempt. [Check MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=netcore-3.1)

> This interface inherits the IEnumerable interface so that if it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated. Enumeration forces the expression tree associated with an IQueryable object to be executed. Queries that do not return enumerable results are executed when the Execute(Expression) method is called.

On top I would suggest to check all the incoming parameters before you will apply it to the query

```
if(dynamicfilter.ContainsKey("name") 
    && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dynamicfilter["name"]))
{
    var nameFilter = dynamicfilter["name"].ToLower();
    query = query.Where(u=>u.Name.ToLower().Contains(nameFilter);
}
```